# How can I query ARPU and ARPPU of a country of my app in Firebase?

Tags: firebase

Basically, title.

I use firebase to monitor my app.

There is a dashboard for summary ARPU and ARPPU but there is no option for country filter as far as I know.

How would I do this?

[image]

So this is the dashboard basically, which contians all the countries.
I can click on the View revenue button but there is no filter for countries.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Alternative solution to get the same data would be also useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Google Play Support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6263332?hl=en), here is what you should do to get the ARPU by country:

**View average revenue per user by acquisition channel or country**

> If your app offers in-app purchases or subscriptions and you have
>   “View financial data” permissions, you can view your app’s average
>   revenue per user (**ARPU**) by acquisition channel or **country**. You can use
>   this data to optimize your acquisition strategies and understand where
>   your most valuable users come from.
>
> 1. Sign in to your Play Console.
> 2. Select an app.
> 3. On the left menu, click User Acquisition > Acquisition reports.
> 4. Select the Buyers tab.
> 5. Set up the details of your report:
>
>    - To switch between acquisition channel and country views, use the "Measure by" drop-down.
>    - To adjust how long you want to track how much users spent after viewing your store listing for the first time, use the “Visitors from”
>        drop-down. Below each acquisition channel or country, the average
>        revenue per user (ARPU) is available for each category of users.

It seems that you can also use the statistics reports:

*From [Google Play support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139628?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en):*

> Set up your report
>
> 1. Sign in to your Play Console.
> 2. Select an app.
> 3. On the left menu, click Statistics.
> 4. At the top-right of your screen, select the date range you want to view.
> 5. In the “Configure report” section, select the metric you want to view using the blue down arrow.
> 6. Define how the metric is calculated and displayed (your chosen metric will determine what options are available to you): ​
> 7. If you want to plot a second metric to compare to the first, click Add a metric. You can configure your second second metric as described
>      above.
> 8. Select the down arrow to choose the dimensions you want to apply, such as countries or Android versions, to display on the chart
>      displayed below your selections. If you want to plot a subset of a
>      dimension such as a specific version of Android or **country**, click
>      Add.
>
>    - Here are the dimensions available on your Statistics page:
>
>      - ...
>      - Country: User's country